# Getting the id value

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I'm working with JavaScript & FrameWork7.

I am using the accordion element, and when I open the accordion I have to "identify" which item was opened, so I have on a variable the html element but I don't know how cand I get the "id" value

I'm using this to get the "element" open

```
app7.on('accordionOpen',function (el) {
  console.log(el);
};
```

So, the console print this..

```
        <li class="accordion-item">
          <a class="item-content">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title" id="numero_jornada">Jornada 1</div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="accordion-item-content">
            <div class="block" id="show-resul-jor-1">

            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
```

How can I get the value for the Id="numero_jornada" ?

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

try to use document.getElementByID("numero_jornada").value;

Comment: Hi Balaji.... All the accordion's element has the same id ("numero_jornada") so I only want the ID for the element open

Answer (score 0):

If your el is a normal HTMLElement, you can simply use el.id as its is in the HtmlElementNode Interface

Answer (score 0):

works, thanks

```
 let titulo = el.querySelector('.item-title');
 // Mostrar ID del título
 console.log(titulo.id);           // numero_jornada
 // Mostrar contenido del título
 console.log(titulo.textContent);  // Jornada #
```